# image display lookup table and window width/level

Tags: image, graphics, jai

I have a general question about image display's **lookup table** with **window width/level**. In my case, we use monochrome display, so there are **256** different pixel values for display on the screen. Our data is signed short type with **only positive values**, so there are **65536** possible different raw data values.

We build the lookup table by mapping the 0 to 65535 **raw data values** with the 0 to 255 **pixel values** originally because we assume all data should be shown up on the screen. The lookup table is an **byte array** with a length of 65536, the mapped pixel values (between 0 to 255) is put into the lookup table array in the way that using raw data value as the **index of the lookup table array** to get the corresponding display pixel value.

Now user changes the Window level and width, say level  = 0, width = 65536 which will display data less than 65536/2, then I have two options:

1. ***Set all lookup table pixel values which is bigger than 65536/2 to 255 (white) AND remapping the 0 to 65535/2 raw data values with 0 – 255 pixel values into the lookup table array;***
2. ***Just set all lookup table pixel values which is bigger than 65535/2 to 255 (white);***

**Which way is correct?** I am thinking the lookup table should be fixed.  If a point is red (if color is used), it should be always red no matter which window level and width user want to look at, I think.  **Right?** If we remapping again based on the new window level and width, that red point may be not red anymore. **Is this good?**